# Must you instantiate "other stores" over and over in Pinia actions?

Tags: pinia

Recently moving from Vuex where the concept of `rootState` was very handy. From any of the modules, you could have access to other module's actions.

With Pinia, inside a store's actions, I've not been able to access "other stores" any way except the example I find on the Pinia pages where you instantiate the "other store" within each action. `const otherStore = useOtherStore().` This is very repetitive. Is there a better less repetitive way?

Comment: You can "use" the store at the top level of the module, as long as you pass in the Pinia instance. `const auth = useAuthStore(pinia)`

Comment: Passing in the Pinia instance is recommended because the module may be run before `app.use(pinia)`, so the Pinia instance would not be injected yet.

Comment: ty, This was helpful.  This worked for one of my stores.  But not the others, because of the order they load I suspect.  I am getting Cannot access 'storeName' before initialization.  Am I supposed to be starting all these stores up in stores/index or somewhere to initialize them earlier?

Comment: Just for reference: The `defineStore` _defines_ the store and `useX` "uses" the store, i.e., returns the store instance. The first call to `useX` also _instantiates_ the store, so that's done "behind the scenes."

Comment: As to the init error, could you share the code?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to include what happened when trying to use at the top of the module.

Comment: You have a circular dependency. JS modules can handle the circular imports, but not the way the stores interact. The store modules are each trying to use the store from the other.

Comment: Pinia Docs say "The easiest way to ensure this is always applied is to defer calls of useStore() by placing them inside functions that will always run after pinia is installed."  I'm looking for once place to do this instead of "Use" inside every action/function.

Comment: The problem is not the Pinia instance here; it's that the store modules are depending on each other.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre]? Then we can look at your issue properly.

Comment: Sorry, newb here. I thought I had? Do you mean more code like how the plugins are started, main.js and app.vue? Or do you mean like a running sandbox?

Comment: is it possible to create all the modules in /store/index.js and export them?
```export default { pinia, store1, store2 }```

Comment: For an MRE, something I can _run_ easily. At the moment, I at the least don't know which of these two stores is being used by calling code. Also, I don't care about Moment.js, etc.; they're irrelevant to the issue. A Stackblitz project or the like would be ideal.

Comment: As the Help page says: _minimal_ (there's unnecessary code currently), _complete_ (we don't have all the code needed to reproduce it ourselves), and _repoducible_ (does the issue still reproduce in the minimal example?).

Comment: I have created the issue in stackBlitz and edited the Question.  Thanks https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-7upuhu?file=public/index.html

Comment: When editing it to reproduce the issue, I instead get `Error in /~/src/store/store2.js (10:39)
(0 , store1_1.useStore1) is not a function`. I believe that this is because of the way the two modules - which are circularly dependant - are interacting, at least within this build setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a working solution](https://%20stackblitz.com/edit/vue-7upuhu?file=public/index.html) that allows stores to be 'used' once and imported into the modules that need them. Included below is some of the code making up the solution.

### store/index.js

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
const pinia = createPinia()

import { useStore1 } from '../store/store1';
import { useStore2 } from '../store/store2';

const store1 = useStore1(pinia)
const store2 = useStore2(pinia)

export { pinia, store1, store2 }
```

### store/store1.js

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { pinia, store2 } from '../store'

export const useStore1 = defineStore('store1', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      store1Property: null,
    }
  },

  actions: {
    setStore2Property(payload) {
      store2.store2Property = payload
      console.log('store2Property', store2.store2Property);      
    },
  },
});
```

### app.vue

```js
<script>
import { pinia, store1, store2 } from './store'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted() {
    store1.setStore2Property('- store2 was set from store1');
    store2.setStore1Property('- store1 was set from store2'); 
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can avoid repetitive code.

There are two syntaxes in Pinia ( https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/ ):

1. Option stores
2. Setup stores

In the *Option stores*, I'm not sure you can instantiate another store globally, but with the *Setup stores*, you can like you can see there https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composing-stores.html#Nested-Stores

```
import { useUserStore } from './user'
    
export const useCartStore = defineStore('cart', () => {
  const user = useUserStore()
  const list = ref([])

  const summary = computed(() => {
    return `Hi ${user.name}, you have ${list.value.length} items in your cart. It costs ${price.value}.`
  })
    
  function purchase() {
     return apiPurchase(user.id, this.list)
  }

  return { summary, purchase }
})
```

About the *Setup stores* syntax :

- `list` becomes a state (because it's a ref)
- `purchase` becomes an action (because it's a function)
- `summary` becomes a getter (because it's a computed)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: As a said in my original comment, you can use `const user = useUserStore(pinia)` at the top level of the module, where `pinia` is the Pinia instance returned by `createPinia()`. This lets you "use" the store once even when using an Options store.

Comment: Both solutions work and are similar. This one uses an import directly inside the store and yours externally.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a Pinia solution for Options stores that doesn't involve receiving the store as a parameter or instantiating it repeatedly, I found a solution that uses a [Pinia plugin](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html).

With the plugin you can declare data that can be accessed with `this` by all stores.

From [an open issue on the Pinia GitHub repo](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1247):

```js
import type { PiniaPluginContext, Store, StoreDefinition } from 'pinia';

declare module 'pinia' {
  export interface DefineStoreOptionsBase<S, Store> {
    stores?: Record<string, StoreDefinition>;
  }

  export interface PiniaCustomProperties<Id, S, G, A> {
    readonly stores: Readonly<Record<string, Store>>;
  }
}

export function piniaPluginStores (context: PiniaPluginContext) {
  return {
    get stores () {
      return Object.freeze(
        Object.entries(context.options.stores ?? {})
          .reduce<Record<string, Store>>((accumulator, [name, definition]) => {
            accumulator[name] = definition();
            return accumulator;
          }, {}),
      );
    },
  };
```

Usage inside store:

```
this.stores[<store_name>]
```

You can use it this way to have access to all stores or adapt it to display only the one you want.